# How to substring a string until a char is not a number

Tags: php

having strings like

```
$string ="1 something here";
$string2=" 345 other string";
```

How can I remove fisrt chars that are numbers?

I know there is a function

```
$str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
$str2 = substr($str, 4);
```

which will remove first 4 chars..

Comment: Try a regular expression instead of a substr, it's going to give you more fine grained control. You can use something like preg_replace() to do this for you. Here is a great regex cheat sheet that should help you get started, and if you need more help just let me know :) http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it very simple with regexp, like this:

```
<?php
      $string ="1 something here";
      $string2=" 345 other string";

      //Pattern matches every number and space char in the beginning of the string
      $pattern = "/^([\s0-9]*)/";

      //echos output
      echo preg_replace($pattern, "",$string);
      echo preg_replace($pattern, "",$string2);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
$pattern = '/^([0-9 ]+)(.*)$/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '$2', trim($string2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regex:

```
function x($str){
   for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
      if(is_numeric ($str{$i}) )
         return substr($str,0, $i);
                 //or substr($str, $i+1); to get from the number until end
   }
   return $str;
}
```